# Blackberry 10 simulator on osx10.9

Tags: blackberry-simulator, vmware-fusion

I have installed [vmware fusion](https://www.vmware.com/in/products/fusion-professional/?src=WWW_Fusion_IN_HPBanner_Learn) on my machine and also downloaded the [simulator](http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_installing.html).

I don't get how to start simulator? I started the vmware app on mac and choose install from another disk and selected the `BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer-BB10_2_1-1055-Mac-201311061539.dmg` file. I then just left it for 30 minutes it still loading.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_installing.html):

1. Run the setup application and follow the instructions in the installation screens. (In your case, mount the .dmg and follow the instructions to install it).
2. Start the simulator: open the folder where you installed the simulator, and double-click **BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_n_nn**, or **BlackBerryPlayBookSimulator-n.n.n**.

You may also encounter Java issues installing, in which case you'll need to install http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Comment: I know this I double clicked on it nothing happens also installed latest java from Apple Site.

Comment: OK, then you'll need to provide more information - be specific in the steps you used to install it, provide your OS version, device, etc.

Comment: I'll try asking on blackberry forms. I am struggling for this for past 1 day.